# Debian GNOME 3 Chrome drag and drop issue

Tags: debian, nvidia, gnome3, chrome

I simply cannot drag and drop anything on Google Chrome; pages (for drag-and-drop bookmarking to the bookmarks bar), tabs (for re-ordering) and also anything on a website (that can be draggable and droppable) creates a link into a directory underneath the Google Chrome's window, or in desktop if there is no windows in between.

I am on 64-bit Debian Jessie, NvidiaGraphicsDrivers installed. I have several workspaces and dual-screen. At the end of the question there is a exhaustive list of specs about the machine.

Here is the steps for reproduction;

- Open Google Chrome
- Right click Google Chrome's title bar and uncheck the "Use system title bar and borders" menu item if it's checked
- Right click on anywhere in the Google Chrome windows while holding Alt key (Alt key is the Window Action Key) and select "Always on Top"
- Right click on anywhere in the Google Chrome windows while holding Alt key and select "Always on Visible Workspace"
- Navigate to another workspace (Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down on my machine)
- Try to re-order any of the tabs
- See an unwanted link created on the directory underneath the Google Chrome's window, or in desktop if there is no windows in between

I am not sure if it is Google Chrome's issue or GNOME's, so I thought you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Specs:

- Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)
- Output of `uname -all`
  Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Output of `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`
  NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.26  Thu Dec  8 18:36:43 PST 2016
  GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1)
- Output of `gnome-shell --version`
  GNOME Shell 3.14.4

**UPDATE**

Strangely this behaviour doesn't occur time to time, but most of the time it arises. So if you want to reproduce the issue please be patient and insistent, or if you want to help keep this occasion in mind.